# How to rename List of Tables? (\renewcommand doesn't work )

Tags: table-of-contents

I'm using `\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Elenco Tabelle, Mappe,Circuiti}`, but it doesn't work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings

%titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%geometry
\geometry{a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.4cm,right=2.4cm,heightrounded}

%fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

%caption
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

%ulem
\normalem

%hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%newcommand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bigskip}{\qquad}
\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Elenco Tabelle, Mappe,Circuiti}



\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\ }} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} blabla \\ \textbf{Cognome:} blabla \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} } 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} }

\begin{document}
    
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

blablabla
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to do the redefinition using `babel` methods.

The traditional method used to be

```
\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}}
```

(you're writing in Italian, aren't you?).

However there's a better method nowadays.

```
\setlocalecaption{italian}{listtable}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}
```

Minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\setlocalecaption{italian}{listtable}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

[image]

If this doesn't work because you have an older TeX distribution, use the traditional method.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\addto\captionsitalian{\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Elenco di tabelle, mappe e circuiti}}

\begin{document}

\listoftables

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Move the `\renewcommand` after the start of the document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside ,titlepage]{article}

%%% packages
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel} 

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textpos}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{karnaugh-map}
\usepackage{ulem}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{hyperref}

%%% settings

%titlesec
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

%geometry
\geometry{a4paper,top=3.5cm,bottom=3.5cm,left=2.4cm,right=2.4cm,heightrounded}

%fancyhdr
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.4pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.8pt}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\thesection\ \ #1}{}}

%caption
\captionsetup{skip=20pt,format=plain,position=bottom,font=small,labelformat=parens,labelfont=bf}

%ulem
\normalem

%hyperref
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

%%%newcommand
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.05}
\newcommand{\overbar}[1]{\overline{#1}}
\newcommand{\HRULE}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\newcommand{\Bigskip}{\qquad}



\title{
\vspace{1.5cm}
\HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.4cm]
\textbf{\Huge\textsc{Progetto\\ }} 
\HRULE{1.2pt}\\ [0.8cm]}
\author{\textbf{Nome:} blabla \\ \textbf{Cognome:} blabla \\ 
\textbf{Matricola:} } 
\date{\textbf{Anno Accademico:} }

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\listtablename}{Elenco Tabelle, Mappe,Circuiti}

    
\setlength{\intextsep}{20pt plus 2pt minus 2pt}

\begin{figure} 
    \centering
%    \includegraphics[width=6cm]{logo.png}
    \HRULE{0.5pt}\\ [0.2cm]
    \Large \texttt{Dipartimento di Ingegneria e Architettura} \\
    \Large\texttt{Ingegneria Eletronica - Informatica} 
\end{figure}

\maketitle 
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

\listoftables
\thispagestyle{empty}
\newpage

blablabla
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: can I divide the sheet into three parts?

Comment: ELENCO TABELLE BLABLABLA

Comment: Elenco Mappe blablabl

Comment: Elenco Circuiti blablabla

Comment: Sorry, but this is not the preferred way of doing it.

Comment: @egreg I know. But I also need to split into three \listoftables name in the sheet

Comment: @LucaLongo I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: @egreg Sei Italiano, parlo nella nostra lingua che è più pratico. La mia voleva essere un'altra domanda. Esiste un modo per suddividere nello stesso foglio la lista delle figure tabelle etc? Senza dover rinominare in quel modo

Comment: @LucaLongo Devi definire nuove classi di oggetti flottanti con il pacchetto `newlistof`.

Comment: @egreg ok, grazie